# How to convert SPC files to ASCII without original spectroscopy software?

Tags: spectroscopy, software

IR and Raman spectroscopy are typically saved in `*.SPC` files ([chemical/x-galactic-spc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_file_format#The_Chemical_MIME_Project)), which are binary files. Collected data is save to SPC files by default, but can be exported to txt (ASCII) files.

I now have original SPC files and the original spectroscopy software is not available. Is it possible to somehow read those files with some other (generic?) software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind Python on the command line, there's an **spc** converter on [Github](https://github.com/rohanisaac/spc).

While the trial version of the [GRAMS Suite 9.2](http://gramssuite.com/Downloads/GRAMS92/Default.asp) is available with a 30 days license, it seemingly doesn't work with any data but the samples provided with it and therefore isn't suitable for your purpose :(

Answer (score 5):

A quick search turned up a number of useful tools. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPC_file_format) suggests:

- [Essential FTIR](http://www.essentialftir.com/fileConversion.html) - which advertises batch conversion of SPC to other formats.
- [SPC2CSV](https://www.analyzeiq.com/Download/SPC2CSV-Utility.html) - from AnalyzeIQ to convert to ASCII CSV format
- [Spekwin32](http://www.effemm2.de/spekwin/index_en.html) - general spectra software, including batch conversion
- [EPA's ShowSPC](https://www3.epa.gov/ttnemc01/ftir/showspc.html) - not clear if it allows saving (or if it even runs on more recent OS)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `R` for data analysis, take a look at the R package [hyperSpec](https://github.com/cbeleites/hyperSpec). Example:

```
install.packages('hyperSpec')
library('hyperSpec')
spectrum <- read.spc('<your spc file>')
...
plot(spectrum)
```

You can also use `Sys.glob()` function for wildcard search of your files, then read all of them with `read.spc()`, and call `collapse()` to build a single hyperSpec class with all data points together.