# how could I make a file conversion from .spc (thermo fisher) in .cdf (Shimadzu) format file?

Tags: chromatography

how could I make a file conversion from .spc (thermo fisher)  in .cdf (Shimadzu) format file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Chemistry but about conversion of file formats.

Comment: [OpenChrom](https://www.openchrom.net/) (open source) should handle both SPC and CDF out of the box, but I haven't used it for years. From what I remember both formats are proprietary (?) and there might be some quirks when using a third-party converter.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51058/how-to-convert-spc-files-to-ascii-without-original-spectroscopy-software